# Android - Play music from url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I tried to play a music from url without downloading, every thing  is write the only problem is that I use below code to play and pause the music, at first by pressing the button the music starts to play and by pressing it again the music paused but if I pressed the button again nothing happens, it should play music from where it was paused but it does not, what is the problem?

```
buttonPlayPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play);
    buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                isPlaying = false;
            } else {
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                new Stream().execute();
            }
        }
    });

private class Stream extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            animation.cancel();
            isPlaying = true;
            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception Caught";
        }
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: why are you checking `v.getId() == R.id.play` in your onClick(View v) method? Are different buttons calling this method?

Comment: you are right, i fixed it

Comment: may be cause you use prepare() not prepareAsync()

Answer (score 0):

In here im using two buttons,
1 for pause and play. another one button for stop.ok lets code,
in your button

> switch case add following codings,
>   btnPlayBack is for pause and play.btnStop for stop playing music.in here i created global MediaPlayer instance named mediaPlayer,

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch ( v.getId() ) {
        case R.id.button_stop_play:
            if ( mediaPlayer != null && buttonAction == 0 ) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonAction = 1;
                btnPlayback.setText("Play");
            }
            else {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    buttonAction = 0;
                    btnPlayback.setText("Pause");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button_stop:
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer = null;
            break;
    }
}
```

> for android back key press, you can also stop playing music by adding this line here

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
```